# My HoloLens 2 shuts off if there is too much text-to-speech

Tags: windows-mixed-reality

I'm creating a training experience using Vuforia Studio for the HoloLens 2. Almost everything works the way it should, there's just one problem. As I stated above, the HoloLens shuts off in the middle of the experience because of the text-to-speech feature being used throughout the experience. I've gotten through up to 23 slides, but then the HoloLens just cut off. That's not even half of the experience. I did some thinking and I thought maybe that it could be a problem with the cache being overloaded and the device needing to reset, but I can't be sure. Has anybody else run into a similar issue and if so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the speech app was getting it's cache overloaded, so I wrote in a cache delete for the speech and now it works fine. I just used <$scope.app.speech.cache.delete();>

Answer (score 0):

For the statement on "HoloLens just cuts off", do you mean the application closes or the device completely powers off?

For further research, it may be worth seeing if any dump files are created by the device via [device portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-hololens#app-crash-dumps-page) and opening a support case with the Microsoft HoloLens support team to review the dumps further.  Here is the link to open the support case:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapid=e9391227-fa6d-927b-0fff-f96288631b8f

The newest OS update for HoloLens 2 released for June c 2020 and does have improved stability updates as noted here too:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes#windows-holographic-version-2004---june-2020-update

Comment: The device would completely power off